# Determining best model for given data

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataset with 2,871 sample points from an aerial photograph in a GIS. Each random point was scored as being in forest (tree = 1) or not (tree = 0). Using a digital elevation model (DEM) that gave the height to the nearest meter (Elevation.m) one other variable was derived. The other variable was a factor variable describing if the sample point was more or less east facing (E.vs.W. = east) or west facing (E.vs.W. = west).

ex:

```
E.vs.W,Elevation.m,tree
west,7.896944379,1
west,6.897992018,1
west,-7.314651138,1
west,-10.88583519,1
west,128.6587367,1
west,102.8423517,1
west,205.0537347,1
west,169.6836871,1
west,201.2179048,1
west,210.6947441,1
...
```

This is sort of homework so I'm not really looking for an answer, just pointers.

I'm to "explore the variables and their interactions to predict the presence of a tree. Find the best model while showing how it compares to the other models using ΔAIC."

This is what I have:

```
dat <- read.csv("Data/treeData.csv")
head(dat)
str(dat)

mod1 <- lm(Elevation.m~tree, data=dat)
mod2 <- lm(Elevation.m~E.vs.W, data=dat)
AIC(mod1,mod2)

plot(Elevation.m~E.vs.W, data=dat)
```

I guess I'm not sure how to pick the "best model". Am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: I suggest first making scatterplots of the data to see if anything obvious turns up during visual inspection. For eample, first a scatterplot of only the West data and a second scatterplot of only the East data.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth I updated it a bit. Would it help if I posted the file with the data?

Comment: *Describing* your data would be a lot better than posting your data. What are the goals of the modeling? Modeling is not an end in itself...

Comment: @Gregor I re-edited it with hopes that it is more clear now. But, the goal is to be able to predict the presence of trees.

Comment: So I'm guessing we are looking at whether trees are present given the altitude/direction. Perfectly fine to use linear modelling, as long as you reverse your variables! `lm(tree~Elevation.m+E.vs.W)` is one model. One method would be to divide your data into k-folds, say k=10 different sets. Then fit the model with 2,871*9/10 of those sets then for each of the 10 combinations, use the remaining 2,871*1/10 sets to test the model. This is called k-fold validation. You could then compute the MSE for each of the 10 folds and each of the models as well as use AIC, BIC or R-squared to compare models!

Comment: @Tony One ordinarily would not choose least-squares or comparison of $R^2$ for a binary response.  Logistic regression (`glm`) would be more appropriate.  Cross-validation is unnecessary at this stage, because the purpose most likely is *explanation* rather than *prediction.* (The way in which those variables are recorded is bizarre, however: aspect, which is crucially important, has been reduced to a binary variable while elevation is recorded to a tenth of a micron!)